# Why my stored procedure is always receiving NULL parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've created a T-SQL script which works very well when I execute it directly. Then I've put this script into a stored procedure with 2 parameters but when I execute it, there is no rows affected... then I've found my 2 parameters are always received as NULL by my stored procedure.

I've tried to set default parameters values inside the create stored procedure script, but even that way, they are NULL.

I've tried to not declare the parameters as scalar variable inside the `@SQLString` since they already are created with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` as parameters but I got the error :

> The scalar variable must be declared

when I tried to execute my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertMetierEventRelation]
    @metier NVARCHAR(50),
    @evenement NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @SQLString = N'     
        DECLARE @rowId INT, @metier NVARCHAR(50), @evenement NVARCHAR(50)
        SELECT @metier AS metierParam -- always NULL
        SELECT @evenement AS evenementParam -- always NULL
        SELECT met_id FROM [dbo].[t_metier] WHERE [met_nom] = @metier 
        SELECT eve_id FROM [dbo].[t_evenement] WHERE [eve_nom] = @evenement 
        -- some other code
        '
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
END
GO
```

I call my stored procedure this way :

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_InsertMetierEventRelation] 
           @metier = 'Organisation de mariage', 
           @evenement = 'Evènement religieux';
```

or this way :

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_InsertMetierEventRelation] 
           'Organisation de mariage', 'Evènement religieux';
```

I got the same result :

```
metierParam NULL 
evenementParam NULL 
met_id NO RESULT 
eve_id NO RESULT
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks you @marc_s I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need dynamic SQL? What happens if you simplify it as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertMetierEventRelation]
    @metier NVARCHAR(50),
    @evenement NVARCHAR(50)
AS

    SELECT met_id FROM [dbo].[t_metier] WHERE [met_nom] = @metier 
    SELECT eve_id FROM [dbo].[t_evenement] WHERE [eve_nom] = @evenement
```

And then run the `EXEC [dbo].[sp_InsertMetierEventRelation] ...`

If you do need dynamic SQL then see answer from John Cappelletti.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know what I'm doing, I'm very new with creating stored procedure. I thought dynamic sql and regular sql was the same. Thanks for your help, it works very well this way ! :)